# How to create nested textview using hyperlinks

Tags: android, android-layout

I would like to create a FAQs as Help for my app. Currently my help section for my app is only one xml with an activity. The xml has only one textview and one return button. Now I want to change it to list of hyperlinks(FAQs), and when an user clicks on the hyperlink a text message(textview) should be displayed. How I can do this?

Comment: I am asking for help in big picture. Not for code.

Answer (score 0):

As for the list of FAQs. You can use a RecyclerView which you will provide to it the list of FAQ's you want to display.

For the message you can use a Toast, SnackBar or even use the hyperlink to open up in the browser itself.